# fullCalendar - drag a non-allDay event to span multiple days - all from 'week' view?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullCalendar working fairly well. However, I would like to be able to drag an event which is *not* `allDay` and drag it to span multiple days.

For example: I have an event that is slotted in for Feb 5, from 10am - 12pm. I'd like to be able to drag the event to the right so that it spans multiple days. The end result being an event that spans from Feb 5, 10am - Feb 9, 12pm (or basically any day after than the original).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: So are you saying that you want one event to span from the Feb 5th 10 am to the 9th 12 pm, is that correct? I just tested using the demo calendar and it works that way now? I am assuming you want separate events for each day from 10-12?

Comment: You are correct. However, this doesn't work in WEEK view - only in month view. In week view (on the demo site) I see an event from 10:30am-12:30pm (the "meeting). In this WEEK view, how can I pull it to span multiple days? Like, grab the right edge of the event and drag horizontally? That's what I'm getting at and, I don't think this is built in yet.

Answer (score 0):

To resize over multiple days and create an event from 10-12 each individual day use the snippet below.

To resize one event across multiple days and keep the same start time and end time, the plugin resize already does that?

See the eventResize callback. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
        // events here
        ],
editable: true,

eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {

   if(dayDelta >= 1 && !event.allDay) {
        revertFunc();

        for (var i = 0 ; i < dayDelta ; i ++) {
           var newEvent = {
            id: event.id,
            title : event.title,
            start : new Date(event.start),
            end : new Date(event.end),
            allDay : event.allDay
           };

           newEvent.start.setDate(newEvent.start.getDate()+(i+1));
           newEvent.end.setDate(newEvent.end.getDate()+(i+1));
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent , 'stick');
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: But it doesn't do this in week view. To accomplish this, I have to span it across multiple days in MONTH view first, then return to week view. I'm just wondering if this is doable in week view alone (without switching views)

Comment: I don't think you can do this in the agendaWeek. Switch to the basicWeek view. This allows you to resize the event left and right.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/